# alternative python replace

Tags: python

I was wondering if there was an alternative to the code below because, 1: there is an error, and 2: i don't want to constantly do:

```
restring=string.replace("a","01").replace("b","02")...
```

Code to possible replace:

```
chars=["a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n","o","p","q","r","t","s","u","v","w","x","y","z"]
numbs=["01","02","03","04","05","06","07","08","09","10","11","12","13","14","15","16","17","18","19","20","21","22","23","24","25","26"]
string="test";
restring=string.replace(chars,numbs);
print restring;
```

Comment: Use a loop, at the very least.

Answer (score 3):

Here, since you only have 1 character replacement "keys", I would use a dict and `join`:

```
>>> chars=["a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n","o","p","q","r","t","s","u","v","w","x","y","z"]
>>> numbs=["01","02","03","04","05","06","07","08","09","10","11","12","13","14","15","16","17","18","19","20","21","22","23","24","25","26"]
>>> d = dict(zip(chars,numbs))
>>> my_sentence = "foobar"
>>> ''.join(d.get(c,c) for c in my_sentence)
'061515020118'
```

This doesn't scale to multiple character replacement keys though ...

Comment: And the first bit could be compressed to `{v: '{:02d}'.format(k) for k,v in enumerate(string.ascii_lowercase, 1)}` or something to avoid hardcoding long lists.

Comment: @DSM +1, put it in an answer!

Comment: @DSM -- Yeah, I had thought about that.  But I didn't want to put things too far from what OP had originally